# Write list of dictionaries to CSV from file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to write a list of dictionaries from a file to a new CSV file. Here's my code to do that.

```
import csv

myfile = open(filename, 'r')
tocsv = myfile.read()
myfile.close()

keys = tocsv[0].keys()
with open(filename.join('.csv'), 'w+') as outputfile:
    dictwriter = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, keys)
    dictwriter.writeheader()
    dictwriter.writerows(tocsv)
```

However, in line 7, `keys = tocsv[0].keys()`, python interprets `tocsv` as a string, which stops me from using the `keys()` function. And I can't use `eval` here because it's a list of dictionaries, so I'm stuck. Any help welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is a well formed list of dicts, you can look use `json.load()` instead of `file.read()`. If it isn't wellformed for json you couldlook into `ast.literal_eval` to turn the data into a `dict`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a list of dictionaries in a file. `dict`s are in-memory data structures. There are various tools such as `json` and `pickle` that will write a serialized version of the dict to disk. They could even be python source code. The thing is, you need to know what format this list takes and use the right tool to decode. BTW, posting a sample here would help us guess.

Comment: I'm not sure that `filename.join('.csv')` is doing what you think it is doing...

Answer (score 0):

Try `json.load()` and see if the list of dicts are well-formed JSON:

```
import json
with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    tocsv = json.load(myfile)
keys = tocsv[0].keys()
...
```

Otherwise try the `ast` module to evaluate the literal:

```
import ast
with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    tocsv = ast.literal_eval(myfile.read())
keys = tocsv[0].keys()
...
```

Note: dictionaries are not ordered so the keys may not be in the same order as the original dictionaries.

Comment: @Ricardo_Bello I had to rollback the edit. `json.load()` takes a file object, `json.loads()` takes a string object. It is incorrect to `myfile.read()` for `json.load()`.